# В каких случаях компилятор применяет RVO/NRVO?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

По моему вопросу мне пока известна только одна статья, в которой хоть как-то описано применение NRVO. Статья из MSDN: [Named Return Value Optimization in Visual C++ 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx). Однако, меня смущает год написания этой статьи и появляется вопрос: А какое текущее положение дел? Ведь на дворе не 2005, а 2016-й!

В этой статье оговорены три причины, когда НЕ сработает:

- Different paths returning different named objects.
- Multiple return paths (even if the same named object is returned on all paths) with EH states introduced.
- The named object returned is referenced in an inline asm block.

Поменялось ли что-нибудь с тех пор?

Answer (score 3):

С тех времён добавилось только move-сементика, соответственно стало больше оптимальных путей по возврату из функции по значений.

С другой стороны, теперь принудительное `std::move()` может помешать применению NVRO. Тут я не знаю, что лучше: оставиться `move` и гарантированно получить перемещение, либо убрать, но получить варианты: NVRO, перемещение или копирование.

Неплохо заглядывать в баг-трекеры компиляторов. К примеру GCC:

1. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53637
2. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58051
3. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58055

По динамике (особенно ссылкам 1 и 3), возникает ощущение (NVRO появилось в GCC в 3.1: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.1/changes.html), что там не сильно разгуляться можно.

В первом баге есть ссылка на интересное исследование, достаточно новое (обновлено где-то в августе 2015, согласно версии gcc из транка), по проверке разных компиляторов в возможностях оптимизации лишних копирований: http://www.byte-physics.de/cpp-copy-elision.